# Dynamically adjust the column and row of a Table Layout based on orientation

Tags: android

Is it possible for my android application to dynamically adjust the no of column and no of row of my TableLayout based on orientation?

For example, when in landscape mode, the TableLayout is 3x2 and when
in portrait mode, the TableLayout is 2x3?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two Folders to hold two different Xml files that will each represent the two TableLayout configurations.

The **layout** folder will hold the normal portrait set up.

And create a folder called **layout-land** and put the landscape setup in here.

Then when the device switches to landscape mode your app will switch to the setup in layout-land and vice versa.

Be aware that you will have to save and reload any data you wish to persist